# Hints on application deployment on Oracle Weblogic AS (WebLogic Server: 10.3.4.0)

Tags: java, deployment, weblogic, classloader

I have a requirement to manage in a single WLS node a stack like this:
--------- Level 1 -----------
Application A:
It's a listener of TCP streaming buffers => it (almost) never changes

--------- Level 2 -----------
Application B:
 
It has the logic to route different TCP streams to various application modules in level 3 (based on patterns in the TCP stream) => It varies upon configuration and not redeployment

--------- Level 3 -----------
Application(s) C,D,E...:
 
They contain logic to transform raw TCP bytes in Java Beans. Each Application manages its own packets and is standalone respect to the other applications at the same level.

The requirement are that:

1. I can update each Application at level 3 without affecting the other modules
2. I must have visibility between Application B and an entry class in each Application at level 3 (such as Class.forName())

   **What kind of deployment architecture would you suggest?**


   Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

If each App at level 3 is independent but still has to have common classloader (and share libraries of level 2), I suggest:

1. Create common JAR/EAR for level 2 and deploy it as a shared library as described here.
   http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11035_01/wls100/programming/libraries.html#wp1071514
2. If the multiple apps at level 3 have stuff in common and are not meant to be independent modules, bundle them into a single EAR else keep them as independent JARs